# Converting JPA Entities to a Map

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, entity

I'm pretty new to JPA and databases in general, and I'm trying to teach myself some of this. I want to know if it's at all possible to turn a List you retrieve of a particular entity into a map. Ultimately I want to get a List of Maps of the all the separate entities.

This is the error that I am getting:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: consultant.billing.entity.WorkEntry cannot be   cast to java.util.Map
```

Below is my entity and the code I am trying to run:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "work_entry")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "WorkEntry.findAll", query = "SELECT w FROM WorkEntry w"),
@NamedQuery(name = "WorkEntry.findByWorkEntryId", query = "SELECT w FROM WorkEntry w WHERE w.workEntryId = :workEntryId"),
@NamedQuery(name = "WorkEntry.findByDate", query = "SELECT w FROM WorkEntry w WHERE w.date = :date"),
@NamedQuery(name = "WorkEntry.findByHoursWorked", query = "SELECT w FROM WorkEntry w WHERE w.hoursWorked = :hoursWorked")})
public class WorkEntry implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "work_entry_id")
private Integer workEntryId;
@Column(name = "date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;
// @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
@Column(name = "hours_worked")
private Double hoursWorked;
@JoinColumn(name = "activity_id", referencedColumnName = "activity_id")
@ManyToOne
private Activity activityId;
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
@ManyToOne
private Customer customerId;

public WorkEntry() {
}

public WorkEntry(Date date, Double hoursWorked, Customer customerId, Activity activityId) {
    this.date = date;
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    this.activityId = activityId;
    this.customerId = customerId;
}


public WorkEntry(Integer workEntryId) {
    this.workEntryId = workEntryId;
}

public Integer getWorkEntryId() {
    return workEntryId;
}

public void setWorkEntryId(Integer workEntryId) {
    this.workEntryId = workEntryId;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public Double getHoursWorked() {
    return hoursWorked;
}

public void setHoursWorked(Double hoursWorked) {
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
}

public Activity getActivityId() {
    return activityId;
}

public void setActivityId(Activity activityId) {
    this.activityId = activityId;
}

public Customer getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(Customer customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (workEntryId != null ? workEntryId.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof WorkEntry)) {
        return false;
    }
    WorkEntry other = (WorkEntry) object;
    if ((this.workEntryId == null && other.workEntryId != null) || (this.workEntryId != null && !this.workEntryId.equals(other.workEntryId))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "consultant.billing.entity.WorkEntry[ workEntryId=" + workEntryId + " ]";
}
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByCustomerId", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.customerId = :customerId"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByFirstName", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.firstName = :firstName"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByLastName", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.lastName = :lastName"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByStreetAddress", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.streetAddress = :streetAddress"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByCity", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.city = :city"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByState", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.state = :state"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByPostalCode", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.postalCode = :postalCode"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByPhoneNumber", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.phoneNumber = :phoneNumber"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByEmail", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.email = :email")})
public class Customer implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "customer_id")
private Integer customerId;
@Size(max = 75)
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Size(max = 75)
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
@Size(max = 250)
@Column(name = "street_address")
private String streetAddress;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "city")
private String city;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "state")
private String state;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "postal_code")
private String postalCode;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "phone_number")
private String phoneNumber;
// @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
@Size(max = 250)
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerId")
private Collection<ExpenseEntry> expenseEntryCollection;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerId")
private Collection<WorkEntry> workEntryCollection;
```

code I'm trying to run:

```
public Customer() {
}

String customerId = request.getParameter("customerId");
            Customer customer = customerServ.find(Integer.parseInt(customerId));
            request.setAttribute("customer", customer);

            String sDate = request.getParameter("sDate");
            Date parsedSDate = sdf.parse(sDate);
            java.sql.Date sqlSDate = new java.sql.Date(parsedSDate.getTime());

            String eDate = request.getParameter("eDate");
            Date parsedEDate = sdf.parse(eDate);
            java.sql.Date sqlEDate = new java.sql.Date(parsedEDate.getTime());

            List<Map> workDone = workServ.getWorkDoneByCustAndDate(Integer.parseInt(customerId), sqlSDate, sqlEDate);
            List<Map> expenses = expenseEntServ.getExpenseForCustIdAndDate(Integer.parseInt(customerId), sqlSDate, sqlEDate);

            List newInvoice = invoice.getInvoice(workDone,expenses);
```

Method I'm using to get WorkEntry:

```
public List<Map> getWorkDoneByCustAndDate(int custId, Date sDate, Date eDate) {
    String jpql = "SELECT w FROM WorkEntry w WHERE w.customerId.customerId = :customerId AND w.date BETWEEN :sDate AND :eDate";
    Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(jpql);
    q.setParameter("customerId", custId);
    q.setParameter("sDate", sDate, TemporalType.DATE);
    q.setParameter("eDate", eDate, TemporalType.DATE);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: The error is saying that the method is returning a single `WorkEntry` but you are trying to turn it into a `List<Map>`  This does not make sense.

Comment: It's multiple entries that I am getting back. Not a single one

Comment: Please show your method definition for `getWorkDoneByCustAndDate`

Comment: Edit to show method.

Comment: it returns a List not a Map as per javadcos http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList()

Comment: Ultimately what I want to do is a get a List of Maps so I can cycle through each Map, but I keep getting the error I list.

Comment: so what is the `key` for the `Map`?

Comment: the key would be the column names and then the value would be whats stored for each one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that but no with JPA, after you get the list of your Work Entries, you can use Java reflection or more easier, use BeanUtils or JACKSON to convert any Java Bean ( in your case, WorkEntry class) into a Map.

You can see this example of BeanUtils library to achieve this goal.

[beanUtils example](http://www.javadb.com/using-beanmap-class-from-apache-commons-beanutils/)

You can add this code after you get your list:

```
List<Map> yourList=new ArrayList<Map>();
   List<WorkEntry> list=q.getResultList();
   for(WorkEntry we:list){
       BeanMap map=new BeanMap(we);
       yourList.add(map);
   }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So that worked, my next question is each map is showing something like "activityId => consultant.billing.entity.Activity[activityId=200]", how can I pull out the value like "consultant.billing.entity.Activity[activityId=200] from the list of maps. I tried to do an if statement where record.get("activityId").equals(), but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you share your code? Are you trying to print each value of your map?   I'm not sure if I understand what are you trying to do with your List of map, but this is my idea:
    <pre><code>
    `for(Map mapOfWorkEntry:listOfMaps){`
        `System.out.println("Map:"+mapOfWorkEntry);`
        `Activity act=(Activity)mapOfWorkEntry.get("activity");`
        `System.out.println("Activity name:"+act.getActivityName()+"| Activity Id:"+act.getId());`
        `Double hours=(Double)mapOfWorkEntry.get("hoursWorked");`
        `System.out.println("Hours:"+hours);`
        }
    </code></pre>

Comment: Basically I'm trying to do this:  'for (Map record : workDone) {
            if (record.get("activityId").equals(10)) {
                nonBillableHours += +Double.parseDouble(record.get("hoursWorked").toString());'

Comment: Ok, got it, you have an error in this line: <br/>
record.get("activityId").equals(10)

The record.get("activityId") will return an object (Activity.class object ) and you trying to compare to 10 value, so at the end you are comparing references , this condition never will be true. To achieve that you need this:<br/>

`Activity activity=record.get("activityId");`<br/>
`Integer id=activity.getId();//Im not sure if your activity class has this property.`<br/>
`if(id==10){`<br/>
`     //do something`<br/>
`}`<br/>

Comment: Also, when you're working with JPA to access to each property of nested object you will do by accessing first this nested object, in your case, you want to access to "activityId" which is inside of your Activity entity, which this Activity class is a nested object of your WorkEntry class, you need to get first the workEntry object, then the Activity object, and finally you can get the "activityId" property from this object. Remember if you mapped the activityId as an object using @ManyToOne, you have a nested object, thats why you need to access first to the Activity class.

Comment: I will try this. Thank you for taking your time to answer, Victor

Answer (score 0):

It's too late  but this example is very practical and can help you

```
ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Map> yourList=new ArrayList<Map>();
List<WorkEntry> list=q.getResultList();
for(WorkEntry we:list){
   yourList.add(oMapper.convertValue(we , Map.class);
}
```